# How do I make max() function only out put a single row

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, sql-order-by, inner-join

```
Select MAX(end_contract-start_contract), job_description, employer_name
FROM contracts join jobs on contracts_job = jobs_id
              join employers on contracts_client = employer_id
WHERE contracts_end is not NULL
GROUP BY jobs_id,jobs_desc,employer_name
```

This query currently outputs:

```
MAX(end_contract-start_contract) jobs_desc        employer_name                      
-------------------------------- --------------- ------------------------------
                             153 Janitor         Microsoft              
                              80 Soldier         Microsoft              
                             119 UNDEFINED       USPS       
                             290 UNDEFINED       Microsoft              
                              89 Pilot           USNC                     
                             119 Cook            USNC                    
                             232 driver          USNC                     
                             340 Soldier         USMC
```

I want the output to be:

```
MAX(end_contract-start_contract) jobs_desc        employer_name                      
-------------------------------- --------------- ------------------------------
                             340 Soldier         USMC
```

That's why I used max() but I can't figure out why it's not just showing the max value. I am very new to SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be more intuitive:

```
Select CONTRACT_END-CONTRACT_START, JOB_DESC, EMP_NAME
FROM CONTRACT join JOB on CONTRACT_JOB = JOB_ID
          join EMPLOYER on CONTRACT_CLIENT = EMP_ID
WHERE CONTRACT_END is not NULL
AND CONTRACT_END-CONTRACT_START=(Select MAX(CONTRACT_END-CONTRACT_START) FROM CONTRACT)
```

Comment: i'm getting an error from your solution I don't know why 
ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 5 Column: 1

Comment: I just edited it.  You have to take these with a little salt.  The idea was there, but it might be right now.  I didn't test it.

Comment: I'm sorry you are right it was a simple edit. Works now thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I *suspect* that aggregation is not doing something useful in your code. If you want the contract with the longest duration, you can just `order by` and `fetch`:

```
select c.contract_end - c.contract_start as contract_days, j.desc, e.emp_name
from contract c
inner join job j on c.contract_job = j.job_id
inner join employer e on c.contract_client = e.emp_id
where c.contract_end is not null
order by contract_days desc
fetch first 1 row with ties
```

Comment: when I use as "contract_days" I'm getting an error: 
ORA-00904: "CONTRACT_DAYS": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Comment: @Millidan . . . When you use it where?  It should be fine in the `order by` clause.